# How to make this jquery code shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to make this code smaller into 1 block?

```
$('#product INPUT:checked').each(function () {
         data.box1.push({
              id: $(this).attr("id")
         });
});


$('#product .dropSelect OPTION:selected').each(function () {           
      data.drops.push({
            value: $(this).val()
      });
});


$('#product .setSelect OPTION:selected').each(function () {           
      data.set.push({
           value: $(this).val()
     });
});
```

Comment: Does the code work? Sometimes shorting isn't the best solution when it mean retaining clarity and functionality.

Comment: yeah if this code works its very simple... Nice on the eyes and not complicated... if you would try to put this into one block it may become unreadable and messy.

Comment: @user791022: then don't shorten for the sake of shortening sake, shorten for efficiency or performance. As it stands, there's not too much you can do without being tricking and deriving the target array off the .*Select class names, but that's more overhead than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can combine the second and third blocks easily using a test:

```
$('#product OPTION:selected').each(function () {           
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("dropSelect")) {
        data.drops.push({
            value: $(this).val()
        });
    } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass("setSelect")) {
        data.set.push({
            value: $(this).val()
        });
    } // end if
});
```

While this isn't much shorter, it has the advantage of saving jQuery the trouble of selecting elements using classes, which is more intensive than selecting IDs or tags. By testing the existence of a class on a single element instead of on the entire document, you should improve your overall performance. (Granted it probably won't be a noticeable improvement, but optimization is rarely a bad thing.)

Comment: Indeed, this is another route to take. And not saying it's wrong, but I'd prefer going through the OP's code 1, 2, 4 weeks/years from now than this any day. Brief and concise; the way code should be.

Comment: @BradChristie: Clean, readable code is good; efficient code is better. Good commenting is the bridge that gets a programmer the best of both worlds.

Comment: You've never had to go through code that the comments are 3 revisions ago and the "new guy" didn't update them--have you? Also, "good code", imho, should be self-commenting.

Comment: @BradChristie: Your example is one of *bad* commenting, which only underscores my point. But I'm not interested in debating this here when other, better developers have already done it for me elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

this shall work, note I prefer to use variables for readability and performance.

```
var $product = $('#product');
var selector = 'INPUT:checked, .dropSelect OPTION:selected, .setSelect OPTION:selected';

$(selector, $product).each( function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.is('INPUT:checked') ) data.box1.push( { id: this.id } );
    if ( $this.hasClass('dropSelect') ) data.drops.push( { value: this.value } );
    if ( $this.hasClass('setSelect') )  data.set.push( { value: this.value } );     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to make it shorter, but if you want it more modular you could try an approach like this:

```
function pushItems(items, dest, objFunc) { 
   items.each(function(i, el) { dest.push(objFunc(el)); });
}
function extractId(el) { 
   return { id: $(el).attr('id') };
}
function extractValue(el) { 
   return { value: $(el).val() };
}

pushItems($('#product INPUT:checked'), data.box1, extractId);
pushItems($('#product .dropSelect OPTION:selected'), data.drops, extractValue);
pushItems($('#product .setSelect OPTION:selected'), data.set, extractValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#product').each(function(){
    $(this).children('input:checked').each(function(){
        data.box1.push({
              id: $(this).attr("id")
         });
    })
    $(this).children('.dropSelect OPTION:selected').each(function(){
        data.drops.push({
            value: $(this).val()
      });
    })
    $(this).children('.setSelect OPTION:selected').each(function(){
        data.set.push({
           value: $(this).val()
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what about the OPs code leads you to believe the original selector inferred `#product > .dropSelect`? (At least that's what I gather by your use of `children` over `find`.)

Comment: why votedown if u have better way just write it. If u dont have so this is the shortest way.

Comment: @SedatBaşar: I didn't down-vote; But, with that said, my better way is the OP's version.

Comment: :) I dont understand why downvotes this answer. Isnt that a right answer, or isnt that shorter than the question? I am just trying to help and I think I helped a little bit. But this is what can I do. If I helped I glad. ty all

Comment: The question was to make a block smaller, not better. Even though this is a correct way (maybe better than the question), this is not the answer.